# Is it possible to restrict a specific user to edit a specific custom post.

Tags: user-roles, user-access

I have a site setup with a custom post for team member profiles, blog posts etc ... I am currently setting up user roles so that users can edit certain areas of the site. I currently use Adminimize to restrict user permissions by role, and it works fine.

What I would like to do is to be able to restrict the appropriate user to only being able to edit the team member profile that relates to them (one single post within the custom posts of 'team members)  or that they have permission to do so.

I don't believe that this is possible through Adminimize as its done on a per role basis. Is anybody aware of a possible solution to this that they could recommend, if it is at all possible?

Thanks in advance for any help

Cheers

Noel

Comment: Adminimize handles things via CSS. This is far away from a real "lock out". Everybody who knows how to use a developer toolbar in a browser can gain access to _hidden_ elements.

Comment: See here http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities and please do some research first.

Comment: Kaiser never realised it was handled using only css, also hadn't realised its compatible up to 3.6!

Comment: @BradDalton Have checked roles and capabilites, so I'm assuming its not possible to limit a specific user to a single specific post? It can only be done on a per role basis?

Comment: I can be done. You just need to find the right function.

Comment: @BradDalton I can change a users role to author, set the user as the specific custom post author. This isn't what I was specifically trying to do, as now they can only edit their own posts or custom posts.